# How to add months and get the month of that year in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In **Google Sheets**, I'm trying to figure out a way to add a certain amount of months to a **cell** which would give me the month out of the year. What I don't want to do is add a number of months and get the total amount of months.

```
[Example of what I want to do]
Cell A1 = 6 (As in the month of June)
Cell A2 = 10 (The number of months I want to add to A1)
Logic that I want: Cell A3 = A1 + A2 = 4 (As in the month of April of the following year)

[Example of what I don't want to do]
Cell A1 = 6 (as in the month of June)
Cell A2 = 10 (The number of months I want to add to A1)
Logic that I don't want: Cell A3 = A1 + A2 = 16
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=MOD(A1+A2,12)
```

You can add as many months as you like now.